# Frozen Kwikset door latch

Tags: lock

I was having trouble with this door getting stuck shut, and now it is firmly frozen shut.  This is just a standard latch, not a deadbolt.  I took the knob off, and that does not help. How do I get this door open?

[image: inside view]
[image: Outside view]

i.stack.imgur.com/BhBff.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Easiest: remove the knob or cylinder from the other side, so the center hole is not blocked. You will then see that this hole exposes an inner piece that slides within the housing, which is retracted from the door edge when the knob rotates the piece with the C shaped cross section. You can use a screwdriver to pull this inner piece to the right, retracting the spring latch.

Assuming the latch isn't damaged.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The latch was damaged, so I used a reciprocating saw which solved the problem in about 1 minute. Damage to the door was minimal.